# How to access menu bar with pywinauto without using mouse click methods?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I need my program to work on RDP session without focus.
All three methods are not working via minimized RPD session started by a Task Scheduler

```
app['program'].menu_select('Tools -> Settings...')
```

or

```
app['program']['Tools'].select()     or   app['program']['Tools'].click_input()
app['program']['Settings...'].select()  or  app['program']['Tools'].click_input()
```

After I start my program manually and check the checkbox in menu myself the rest of the program works fine via Task Scheduler through app.connect method.
Is there another method to access this said menu without using a mouse?

Answer (score 0):

All the recipes are collected here: [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html).

Comment: I mean the entire script works fine, but can you launch tools-setting... window diffently? If there is not other way, I will use VNC for sure.

Comment: I used VNC for CI needs on my previous job. This is the best way I know as a pywinauto maintainer.